# How to access iphone's lockscreen and homescreen image in xCode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, lockscreen, homescreen

I want to set the background of my app the same image as it is in the user's iphone lockscreen image, and also I would like to know how to access to homescreen image as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. Unless there's a public API, things outside your app are blocked.

I don't know of an API to access either of those things.

Comment: Okay , Thank You ! and I dont understand why my question got negative votes.